# Calculator Program improvements

Tags: c#, beginner, .net, console, calculator

I'm pretty new to programming and made a few programs so far. I recently made a Calculator program and I hope you guys could tell me what I could do to improve.

```cs
int firstNumber;
string sign;
int secondNumber;
int answer;

Console.WriteLine("Input Number:");
firstNumber = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.Clear();

Console.WriteLine("Input Sign:");
sign = Console.ReadLine();
Console.Clear();

Console.WriteLine("Input Second Number:");
secondNumber = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.Clear();

switch (sign)
{
    case "+":
        answer = firstNumber + secondNumber;
        Console.WriteLine(answer);
        Console.ReadKey();
    break;
    case "-":
        answer = firstNumber - secondNumber;
        Console.WriteLine(answer);
        Console.ReadKey();
    break;
    case "*":
        answer = firstNumber * secondNumber;
        Console.WriteLine(answer);
        Console.ReadKey();
    break;
    case "/":
        answer = firstNumber / secondNumber;
        Console.WriteLine(answer);
        Console.ReadKey();
    break;
    default:
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid Input");
    break;
}
```

Comment: I would split this into 2 functions. One which does the IO, console reads/writes. And another which does the actual calculation; primarily the current switch statement. This would separate the concerns, enabling many advantages like testing & reuse.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### In general

Whenever you try to implement an application try to use sentences to describe the desired behavior. After that ask yourself: *"Can it be further refined?"* If so, then write new sentences to detail your plan in a more fine-grained level.

Let me show you what I mean:

#### The view from 10 000 feet

> The application can perform basic operations between two operands.

What can be further refined?

- What does it mean *basic operation*?
- What did we mean by *two operands*?

#### High-level view

> The application can perform basic operations between two operands.
>
> > It allows addition, subtraction, multiplication and division.

> > User can provide two numbers and the desired operation.
> > The application will perform it on the user's behalf.

What can be further refined?

- How can an *user provide numbers*?

#### Fine-grained problem decomposition

> The application can perform basic operations between two operands.
>
> > It allows addition, subtraction, multiplication and division.

> > User can provide two numbers and the desired operation.
> >
> > > The application receives an input from the user then it perform a preliminary check.
> > >
> > > > If it is valid then it goes to the next statement.
> > > > If it is invalid then it ask the user again to provide a valid input.

> > The application will perform it on the user's behalf.

#### Let's put together the skeleton

Now, we can translate each sentence into instructions.
This problem decomposition also helps us to well-organize our code:

```cs
///<summary>
/// The application can perform basic operations between two operands.
///</summary>
public static void Main()
{

}

///<summary>
/// User can provide two numbers and the desired operation.
///</summary>
private static void AskForInputs()
{

}

///<summary>
/// The application receives an input from the user then it perform a preliminary check.
/// <list type="bullet">
/// <item>
/// <description>If it is valid then it goes to the next statement.</description>
/// </item>
/// <item>
/// <description>If it is invalid then it ask the user again to provide a valid input.</description>
/// </item>
/// </list>
///</summary>
///</summary>
private static int AskForNumber()
{
    
}

///<summary>
/// The application receives an input from the user then it perform a preliminary check. <para />
/// It allows addition, subtraction, multiplication and division.
///</summary>
private static char AskForOperation()
{
    
}

///<summary>
/// The application will perform it on the users behalf.
///</summary>
private static void PerformRequestedOperation()
{
    
}
```

### Observations about your implementation

The implementation is bit naive, because:

- It does not handle those cases when the user provides malformed input

  - For example: instead of `3` (s)he provides `three`
- It does not handle under- or overflow cases

  - For example: `int.MaxValue + 100`
- It does not handle zero division case

  - For example: `100 / 0`
- It does not handle properly a division where the result is a floating number

  - For example: `10 / 3`
- etc.

In your `switch` statement you repeat the following two statement in each `case`:

```cs
Console.WriteLine(answer);
Console.ReadKey();
```

An alternative implementation could be:

```cs
switch (operation)
{
    case "+":
        answer = firstNumber + secondNumber;
    break;
    case "-":
        answer = firstNumber - secondNumber;
    break;
    case "*":
        answer = firstNumber * secondNumber;
    break;
    case "/":
        answer = firstNumber / secondNumber;
    break;
}
        
Console.WriteLine(answer);
Console.ReadKey();
```

This can be easily enhanced to include all the above validations as well:

```cs
switch (operation)
{
    case "+":
        answer = PerformAddition(lhs, rhs);
    break;
    case "-":
        answer = PerformSubtraction(lhs, rhs);
    break;
    case "*":
        answer = PerformMultiplication(lhs, rhs);
    break;
    case "/":
        answer = PerformDivision(lhs, rhs);
    break;
}
        
Console.WriteLine(answer);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Now as you can see we have introduced 4 new functions to abstract away the complexity to deal with different edge cases and the main flow remained easy to follow.

Answer (score 2):

An excellent attempt to writing your Calculator, I find the variable names and syntax following well accepted conventions for nomenclature in C#

One suggestion: anticipate invalid inputs from user. I would recommend using `int.TryParse` in place of `Convert.ToInt32()`.