# My first ever calculator C#

Tags: c#, beginner, calculator

This is my first ever created program I've made. It's not very good but I'm pretty proud of it.

If you have any suggestions I could add into the calculator I would gladly do that.

```csharp
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace CSharp_Shell
{
    public static class Program 
    {
        public static void Main() 
        {
           try
           {
                Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------");
                Console.WriteLine("Operators:");
                Console.WriteLine("+ = Add");
                Console.WriteLine("- = Subtract");
                Console.WriteLine("* = Multiply");
                Console.WriteLine("/ = Divide");
                Console.WriteLine("^ = Power");
                Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------");
                
                Console.Write("Enter operator: ");
                
                string op = (Console.ReadLine());
           
                Console.Write("Enter First Number: ");
                double num1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
          
                Console.Write("Enter Second Number: ");
                double num2 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------");
           
           
                if (op == "+")
                {
                   Console.WriteLine(num1 + num2);
                   Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------");
                }
                else if (op == "-")
                {
                   Console.WriteLine(num1 - num2);
                   Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------");
                }
                else if (op == "/")
                {
                   Console.WriteLine(num1 / num2);
                   Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------");
                }
                else if (op == "*")
                {
                   Console.WriteLine(num1 * num2);
                   Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------");
                }
                else if (op == "^")
                {
                   double value1 = Math.Pow(num1, num2);  
                   Console.WriteLine("{0}", value1);
                   Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------");
                }
                else
                {
                   Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                   Console.WriteLine("error");
                   
                   Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                   Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------");
                }
           }
           catch
           {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------");
                
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.WriteLine("error");
            
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------");
           }
           Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
           Console.Write("Press any key to stop the program");
           Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A couple of days ago a quite similar question had been posted. Please check [my answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/254363/calculator-program-improvements/254374#254374), most of the recommendations can be applied here as well.

Comment: @Chocolate it is not a duplicate. Refer to answer to [this meta post](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8/120114).

Answer (score 4):

Over all, if this is your first time coding, you've really done a stellar job. I'm having a hard time believing this was a first attempt without replicating someone else's code, just because of how cleanly you've approached it. Very well done.

The below suggestions are more *further improvements* than they are corrections on what you were doing. Some of the things I suggest may not make full sense now, but are good habits to breed early on, because when you start working on more complex applications, you'll significantly benefit from not having to learn every mistake the hard way.

---

**Avoid repetition**

How often do you see this code:

```
Console.ForegroundColor = /* some color */;
Console.WriteLine(/* some message */);
```

The answer is **a lot**. So to save yourself some repeated code, abstract it into a method:

```
public void WriteMessage(string message, ConsoleColor color = ConsoleColor.White)
{
    Console.ForegroundColor = color;
    Console.WriteLine(message);
}
```

It seems like a little thing, but it effectively halves amount of lines (revolving around printing logic) in your main method, since you can now just do:

```
WriteMessage("error", ConsoleColor.Red);
```

Note that I also made the color an optional parameter, so it can be omitted when no special color is needed:

```
WriteMessage("a message without special color");
```

**Syntax improvements**

This is just a little thing, but notice how every condition ends with drawing a line:

```
if (op == "+")
{
    Console.WriteLine(num1 + num2);
    Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------");
}
else if (op == "-")
{
    Console.WriteLine(num1 - num2);
    Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------");
}
// and so on...
```

If all of them end on the same instruction, it's easier to just put that instruction behind the if/else:

```
if (op == "+")
{
    Console.WriteLine(num1 + num2);
}
else if (op == "-")
{
    Console.WriteLine(num1 - num2);
}
// and so on...        

Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------");
```

But you can go further. The same applies to printing the result. So you can also move that outside of the chain:

```
double result = 0;

if (op == "+")
{
    result = num1 + num2;
}
else if (op == "-")
{
    result = num1 - num2;
}
// and so on...        

Console.WriteLine(result);   
Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------");
```

**Syntax improvements**

You should avoid `if else` chains where you keep checking if the same variable matches a given value. That's precisely what a `switch` was made for:

```
switch(op)
{
    case "+":
        Console.WriteLine(num1 + num2);
        break;
    case "-":
        Console.WriteLine(num1 - num2);
        break;
    case "*":
        Console.WriteLine(num1 * num2);
        break;
    // and so on...
}
```

**Break it up**

The code you wrote is relatively neat for a beginner program. Good indentation, reasonable whitespace separation between lines.

But the next step is breaking your method down into smaller steps. If I were to sum up what this code does, I'd list it as follows:

- Takes in a number (twice)
- Takes in a mathematical operation
- Writes messages to the console, sometimes in color.
- Performs the selected operation on the selected numbers

You could add a lot more bullet points here if you wanted, e.g whether you consider drawing a horizontal separator as a different task from writing a message to the console. I'm sticking with these four as it's a basic example.

These four bullet points are a great (but not complete) guideline to how you need to break down your application. Anything you consider a separate task, is generally going to want to be in a method on its own. So in this case you'd be looking at methods like:

- `double GetNumber()`
- `char GetOperation()` - I'd consider using a custom enum here instead of a character, but let's keep it simple for now.
- `void WriteMessage(string message, ConsoleColor color = ConsoleColor.White)` - see previous point section
- Separate operator methods:

  - `double Add(double a, double b)`
  - `double Subtract(double a, double b)`
  - `double Multiply(double a, double b)`
  - `double Divide(double a, double b)`
  - `double Power(double a, double b)` - This mirrors `Math.Pow` and you could technically skip your own method and use `Math.Pow` directly. However, due to abstraction considerations, it's good practice to still define your own method. This is maybe beyond your current skill level, but the idea behind it is that if you suppose that you change your calculation logic in the future, it's easier to rewrite the content of your `Power` method once, than it is to go hunt for all references to `Math.Pow` and substitute them all individually.

There's definitely still room for improvement, but you're still a beginner and this is a good first step. Try to write the code in your `Main` method in a way that it relies on these methods I just listed, instead of having the `Main` menu do all the heavy lifting by itself.

Think of it this way: when you stop being a cook and instead become a chef (= better code), then you're no longer doing the small jobs yourself, e.g. peeling the potatoes and washing the dishes. Tasks get delegated. Chefs (the `Main` method) rely on the small things being done by others (the submethods).

**Refactoring**

I noticed this:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}", value1);
```

It's needlessly complex. Just do:

```
Console.WriteLine(value1);
```

I suspect that this is a refactoring remnant. It used to do more than just print `value1`, but over time you changed the code, and never steered away from using the `String.Format` approach.

That's completely normal, but this is precisely why developers should always revisit code when it's "finished", to see if there are some remnants of past attempts that can be cleaned up or refactored into something better.

**A better user experience**

It helps to sometimes think like a user instead of like a developer. When adding 1 and 2 together, how do we write things?

- `+ 1 2`
- `1 + 2`
- `1 2 +`

I hope you'll agree that the second bullet point is vastly preferred. Note that the first bullet point also exists (it's called [Polish notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation)), but unless you have reason to believe that your users predominantly use Polish notation, the second bullet point is how users think.

But when you ask for user input, you are asking for `+ 1 2`:

```
Console.Write("Enter operator: ");
string op = (Console.ReadLine());
       
Console.Write("Enter First Number: ");
double num1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
      
Console.Write("Enter Second Number: ");
double num2 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
```

That doesn't match with how users think. It's a very simple improvement to just change the order of your code. It doesn't change how your code works, but it does improve the user experience.

**An even better user experience**

This is not as simple, but as a next challenge, you could see if you could move away from users having to input separate values and having to press enter inbetween.

See if you can figure out how to let users input the whole formula, e.g. `"1+2"` and take it from there. Or, alternatively, read every key the user presses and dynamically figure out what they mean.

If you think about a real-world calculator, it works without needing to press enter inbetween its data input. So try and make yours similar. It's a great user experience improvement, and a good exercise for someone who's new to coding.

Comment: Thank you very much! This helped a lot, I will try to improve the user input and the UI, and hopefully make the code more simple to read. I was struggling with the Power so I looked up a example of it, but everything else is made by me. I've watched an 4 hour video of how to program, but I think the way to learn more is just to do more programming and improving the code. Again thank you very much for this.

Comment: @Sipuli saying thanks is not enough on Stack Exchange and not a mandatory even if you thankful person. The best way to say thanks is marking the answer as accepted instead. Checkbox is to the left of the answer's text.

Answer (score 2):

## Dividing work

The job of your calculator is to take some input, process it, and show the output to the user. If you split those 3 steps into functions of their own you add a lot of clarity to the person who reads your code. Moreover, you can re-use those functions if you want to perform the same step again.

Something along the lines of

```cs
var numbers  = getNumbersInput();
var op = getOperatorInput();

var result = calcResult(op, numbers.Item1, number2.Item2);
Console.WriteLine($"The result is {result}.");
```

Here it is clear the job of `getNumbersInput()` is to get the two numbers and return them. `getOperatorInput()` will return the operator the user wants to use and `calcResult()` will use the input, process it, and return you the result.

---

## Don't wrap your whole program in a `try/catch`

There are only a few areas where your program can run into an exception. Such as the point where you are taking the integer input from the user. Upon invalid input, you can use `catch` to provide specific errors to guide the user on what he did wrong. Just 2 white lines with the word `error` doesn't tell you what happened does it?

Instead, use `try/catch` in specific areas with proper error messages such as `Invalid number input: Please enter a number`.