# Methods improvements

Tags: c#

I just recently learned how to write Methods in C#. Here is one experiment I made. It calculates addition, subtraction, division, multiplication, and the square root of a number. fill free to give me suggestions on how I can improve the code. I also do know I need to set up a system that prevents the user from typing wrong answers. I just don't have enough experience to do it yet (I tried).

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       string userAnswer;

       Console.WriteLine("Calculater or Square Root Calculater?");
       Console.WriteLine("-Please respond with Calculater or Square");
       userAnswer = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
       Console.Clear();

       switch(userAnswer)
       {
           case "CALCULATER":
            Calculater();
           break;
           case "SQUARE":
            SquareRootCalculater();
           break;
           default:
           Console.WriteLine("Invalid Input");
           break;
       }
        
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

     static void SquareRootCalculater()
    {
        int squareNumber;

        Console.WriteLine("Input Number:");
        squareNumber = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Clear();

        Console.WriteLine($"The Square Root of {squareNumber} is");
        Console.WriteLine(Math.Sqrt(squareNumber));
    }

    static void Calculater()
    {
        int firstNumber;
        string sign;
        int secondNumber;
        int answer = 0;


        Console.WriteLine("Input Number:");
        firstNumber = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Clear();

        Console.WriteLine("Input Operation:");
        sign = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Clear();

        Console.WriteLine("Input Second Number:");
        secondNumber = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Clear();

        switch (sign)
        {
            case "+":
                answer = firstNumber + secondNumber;
            break;
            case "-":
                answer = firstNumber - secondNumber;
            break;
            case "*":
                answer = firstNumber * secondNumber;
            break;
            case "/":
                answer = firstNumber / secondNumber;
            break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid Input");
            break;
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"The answer of {firstNumber} {sign} {secondNumber} is");
        Console.WriteLine(answer);

    }
```

Comment: Please improve the title of your question.

Comment: I have already provided a [thorough answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/254374/224104) for your previous question. Now the same code appears here again. Why?

Comment: Peter Csala. Thank you for your previous answer to the calculater improvement question I put out around a week ago. I have recently learned how to work with methods and was experimenting with it. I decided to reuse some code from the calculater improvement question while experimenting with methods. I put out this question because I was seeking advice on how well I implemented the methods. I also will try to improve the title.

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to **simply state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @the if you look at Peter Csala's answer to your original question https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/254374/47174 he's provided a good example for for a key principal for writing better Methods called *Separation of Concerns* (You should do some research on this topic). If you look at his code that contains `answer = PerformAddition(lhs, rhs);` you'll see he's modified your code to include 4 additional functions. This is a separating those 4 concerns into their own methods, with descriptive names, that makes the code easier to read and maintain.

Answer (score 0):

You should aim to declare variables at initialization when possible. Pre-initialized variables are suspicious and make me wonder whether they are being optionally assigned or edited elsewhere.

```
       // string userAnswer;

       Console.WriteLine("Calculater or Square Root Calculater?");
       Console.WriteLine("-Please respond with Calculater or Square");
       string userAnswer = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
       Console.Clear();
```